# MySQL: SUM of a column based on a value of another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to have a sum of a column that is based if the value of another column is this/that. Here's my table structure

```
id  leave_hours leave_type overtime_hours employee_id
1     7.6          1           0               3
2      5           2           0               3
3      0           0           2.3             3
```

I have this query already but I need to have a column that will only sum if leave type is 1 and if the leave type is 2

```
SELECT employee_id, SUM(overtime_hours) AS ot_hrs, SUM(leave_hours if leave_type == 1) AS  
       leave_1, SUM(leave_hours if leave_type == 2) AS leave_2
FROM table
GROUP BY employee_id
```

Result should be:

```
employee_id  ot_hrs leave_1  leave_2
    3          2.3    7.6       5
```

Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: What do you want to sum?

Comment: Your description is not enough to provide a better solution.

Comment: edited the question to reflect the result and the sum query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use conditional aggregation to sum the different `leave_hours` separately:

```
SELECT employee_id, 
       SUM(overtime_hours) AS ot, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN leave_type = 1 THEN leave_hours ELSE 0 END) AS leave_1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN leave_type = 2 THEN leave_hours ELSE 0 END) AS leave_2
FROM `table`
GROUP BY employee_id
```

Output:

```
employee_id ot      leave_1     leave_2
3           2.3     7.6         5
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pNw42Q4yRiMhA7qFGTEZ4R/0)

Note that if you use floating point numbers to store the hours, you may need to `ROUND` the results.

Comment: When doing this it is nicer to use NULL instead of 0.  That way you don't have the existence of some record you *aren't* counting change the result from NULL to 0.

Comment: don't need the round though but this one works. just edit it without round and I'll set this as the accepted answer.

Comment: The demo on dbfiddle uses `FLOAT` for the numbers, and 2.3 and 7.6 can't be precisely represented as floating point numbers. So I'm rounding them rather than displaying `2.29999999837424` etc.

Comment: @Ronald ROUNDing removed.

Comment: Ah.  Better to use decimal than float for most cases

Comment: @ysth indeed. The default mode of db-fiddle when you just input table data is always to select `FLOAT`, I just need to remember to change it...

Answer (score 1):

you can use `max()` with case when

```
SELECT employee_id, 
       max(overtime_hours) AS ot, 
       max(CASE WHEN leave_type = 1 THEN leave_hours  END) AS leave_1, 
       max(CASE WHEN leave_type = 2 THEN leave_hours END) AS leave_2
FROM  table_name
GROUP BY employee_id
```

output

```
employee_id     ot     leave_1       leave_2
3              2.3  7.599999904632568   5
```

Comment: May I know the reason for using MAX?

Comment: @Ronald you want pivoting which can be done easily by using max() https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pNw42Q4yRiMhA7qFGTEZ4R/2

Comment: @Ronald I'm guessing because your data only showed one record per leave_type/employee; max would then be equivalent to sum.  But I'm guessing you can have more than one.