# Is there a function in SQL that allows me to sum specific rows based on a column value?

Tags: sql, count, sum

I want to sum City4, and the two misspellings together as one row. Any input on how to do this?

```
SELECT column1,
       column2,
       count(column3),
       Sum(Column4)
FROM TABLE
  AND column1 IN ('state1',
                   'State2',
                   'State3')
  AND column2 IN ('City1',
                  'City2',
                  'City3',
                  'City4',
                  'City4 misspelled1',
                  'City4 misspelled 2')

GROUP BY column1,
         column2
ORDER BY column1;
```

Comment: see this: [SUM of a column based on a value of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56388256/mysql-sum-of-a-column-based-on-a-value-of-another-column)

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN substring(culumn2,1,5)='City4' THEN Column4 ELSE 0 END) as TotalForCity4PlusMisspelled`

Comment: The SQL Standard defines the `FILTER` keyword for this. Unfortunately, I think only PostgreSQL implements it, though.